# c# List Query without using Linq

Tags: c#, list

I'm after some help with how to query a list and return back the index, but not using Linq. I've seen many example where Linq is used, but the software I'm writing the query into doesn't support Linq. :(

So example to get us going:

```
List<string> location = new List<string>();
location.add(@"C:\test\numbers\FileName_IgnoreThis_1.jpg");
location.add(@"C:\test\numbers\FileName_IgnoreThis_2.jpg");
location.add(@"C:\test\numbers\FileName_ImAfterThis_3.jpg");
location.add(@"C:\test\numbers\FileName_IgnoreThis_4.jpg");
location.add(@"C:\test\numbers\FileName_ImAfterThis_5.jpg");
```

So this list will be populated with probably a few hundred records, what I need to do is query the list for the text "ImAfterThis" then return the index number location for this item into a string array but without using Linq.

The desired result would be 2 and 4 being added to the string array.

I was thinking of doing a for loop through the list, but is there a better way to achieve this?

```
 List<int> results = new List<int>();

        int i = 0;
        foreach (string value in location)
        {
            if (value.Contains("IAfterThis"))
            {
                results.Add(i);
                Console.WriteLine("Found in Index: " + i);
            }
            i++;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: I think a loop would work - iterate until you find your desired item them break the loop and store the position

Comment: Thanks horHAY, loops are the only way I could think of achieving this.
@DanielA.White - I was after advise, but I see your point and added the foreach loop I was using which works, but was after any other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get just the first occurrence you could simply use the IndexOf() method.

If you want all occurrences of string "whatever" then a for loop would certainly work for you. For the sake of argument here I've capture the indexes in another list:

```
string MyString = "whatever";
List<int> indexes = new List();

for (int i = 0; i < location.Count; i++)
{
    if (location[i] == MyString)
    {
       indexes.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work thanks, I was testing with a foreach loop which I added to my original post to show willing.

I know Linq makes this more simple, but wondering is there was something easier, but I guess not.